# thinking sphinx is giving error on special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using sphinx for search in my web app, now First search was being crashed due to special characters the I use Riddle.escape to stabilize my string before passing it to sphinx but this works fine string when string have some non special characters like this

"!~@#!@asd#!a#@"

but when it goes with only special characters like this

"!#!@#!#$@"

it gives the following error

"index book_core: syntax error, unexpected $end near"
' !#!\@#!#\$\@'

Answer (score 2):

It will give an error either by pass character at the time of searching or
add special character in yml file for searching
using charset table
More info http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html